# Memory issue in storing and retrieving Image from database

Tags: ios, sqlite, memory

I am working on application which include native SQLite database in which I am storing and retrieving images and showing into My application.

Now my problem is Like I am storing lots of images in directory and its path storing into database. So when I retrieve that path from database and load image into application, Memory Increases upto 10-20 Mb per image.

I also tried to store image data into database but same issue, Memory increase 10-20 Mb per image.

Please what should I do for this memory issue ?
Help me with it

Comment: Image take a lot of memory. You need to update your question with how you are using these images. The use of a database is irrelevant to your issue.

Comment: Also, how large are the images (in disk space and in resolution/bit-depth), and how are you loading them (imageNamed:, contentsOfFile, from an NSData)? Are you displaying them or otherwise forcing them to be decoded? How are you storing them (UIImage, CGImage, NSData)? How much memory do you *expect* them to require? As rmaddy notes, images are large. In some cases there's no way around that.

Comment: This SO answer might be useful to figure out your graphics memory usage: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17225377/763355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images, when used in the app, may require considerably more memory than the size of the asset in persistent storage might otherwise suggest. Assets are frequently compressed (e.g. JPG or PNG), but when you use the image, they're uncompressed, often requiring 4 bytes per pixel (one byte for red, green, blue, and alpha, respectively). So, for example, a iPhone 7+ full-screen retina image can require 14mb when you use the image. So, the memory-efficient technique is to employ lazy loading, not creating the `UIImage` objects until you absolutely need them. And, as Jerry suggested, because the amount of memory is determined by the size of the image and not the imageview in which you use the image, if your images have dimensions greater than required by the `UIImageView` in which you use them (i.e. width and height of the imageview times the "scale" of the device), you may want to resize the image accordingly.

Comment: I really appericate your answer, you answer makes my problem solved. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case that the images you are trying to display are much larger than they need to be on the screen.  Try loading the images into memory, creating a version with the size you need, and then using that.  Of course, you could implement some caching so you don't have to keep resizing the same images.  But then when the original image goes out of scope, its memory will be released.  If you always need your images at the same size, try resizing them before storing them in the database, but if you want to support multiple sizes (for different devices, maybe), then store the images at the largest size you need and resize for the others.

Comment: I really appericate your answer, you answer makes my problem solved. Thank you